# How does the melting point of alkynes change with the position of the triple bond?

Tags: organic-chemistry, melting-point

$$
\begin{array}{cc}
\text{1-hexyne}&\pu{-132 ^\circ C}\\
\text{2-hexyne}&\pu{-89.5 ^\circ C}\\
\text{3-hexyne}&\pu{-103 ^\circ C}\\
\end{array}
$$

These are the melting points of six carbon chain alkynes. The boiling point of a molecule is mainly affected by its shape. So, if all this molecules have the same shape, why is the range of temperatures so high ($\pu{42.5 ^\circ C}$)?

Comment: Those molecules do NOT have the same shape, they look quite differently.